# formal smooth morphism with a formal smooth source

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, smooth-manifolds, schemes

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a morpism between $k$-schemes ( $k$ a field).

We suppose that X is formally smooth and f is formally smooth and surjective.

Do we have that $Y$ is formally smooth?

Or if it's not is there weaker hypotheses as every thing is locally of finite type to obtain smoothness of $Y$?

Comment: You write "as every thing is locally of finite type", but prior to that you make no such lft hypothesis, so it is confusing.  If $X$ and $Y$ are locally finite type over $k$ then any $k$-morphism between them is lft (equivalently, locally of finite presentation), and for an lfp map smoothness is the same as formal smoothness by EGA.  So in the lft case, if f is formally smooth then it is smooth, and thus flat.  So then $Y$ inherits $k$-smoothness from $X$, as we can pass up to $\overline{k}$ and use that a noetherian ring is regular if it has a faithfully flat extension ring that is regular. 

Comment: what I meant is that in the lft case it's well known but I would like to know if we can weaken these hypotheses.

Comment: By Theorem 28.7 in Matsumura's "Commutative Ring Theory", a noetherian local $k$-algebra is formally $k$-smooth for its max-adic topology if and only if it is "geometrically regular" over $k$, in the sense that it remains regular after tensoring against any finite extension of $k$. By 19.7.1 in EGA 0$_{\rm{IV}}$, if $X$ and $Y$ are locally noetherian and $f$ between local rings is formally smooth for max-adic topologies then it is *flat*, so $Y$ inherits geometric regularity over $k$ from $X$. So try to relate "global" formal smoothness to max-adic formal smoothness on local rings.

Comment: so it's probably true if X and Y are locally noetherian? To relate global to local, maybe it's sufficient to say that formal smoothness is local for Zariski topology on the source and on the target by 17.1.6 (i) and (ii) in EGA IV.4

Comment: and let say that only Y is locally noetherian and moreover the morphism is faithfully flat?

Comment: @prochet: The issue is to connect up formal smoothness for the max-adic versus discrete topologies for local maps between local noetherian rings, at least as a first step. (Maybe it isn't true?) Then one can try to globalize from there. I don't think it is a good idea to assume flatness (though you have not explained why you posed the question).

Comment: As I told you if $X$ and $Y$ are locally noetherian, as formal smoothness is local for Zariski topology on the source and on the base, I think it implies the local case and we can use your argument to conclude.
I asked the question with flatness because if you made no noetherian assumptions on $X$ and $Y$, then you have example of maps that are formally smooth but not flat and then regularity for $Y$ may fail.
